# Nested drop down menu error

Tags: html, css

Hello I am trying to create a nested drop down menu for my website, however I've come across this error which happens when I code in the options for each subject, the drop down menu glitches out and I don't know how to fix it. I'm not sure on how to solve this and any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```css
html,body{ 
 margin:0; 
 padding:0; 
 height:100%; 
 width:100%; 
 overflow: hidden;

}
body{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
}

   #banner-container{
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 
}

ul{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
ul li{
 text-align: center;
}

ul li ul li{
 display:none;
}

ul li:hover ul li{
 display: block;
}
header{
 background-color: #595959;
 color: #fff;
 padding-top: 30px;
 min-height: 70px;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #FFD700;
}
header a{
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 16px;
}

header li{
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

header .banner{
 float: left;
}

header .banner h1{
 margin: 0;
}

header nav{
 float: right;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

header a:hover{
 color: #ccc;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>

   </head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div id="banner-container">
   <div class="banner">
    <h1>A-Level</h1>
   </div>
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">A-level</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Maths</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">PLC</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Revision</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Exam Papers</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Physics</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">PLC</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Revision</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Exam Papers</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Computer Science</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">PLC</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Revision</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Exam Papers</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li> 
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="index.php">TimeTable</a></li>
     <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from the rule

```
header li{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

This also applies to your sub-navigation items and the `float: left` attribute forces them to arrange over the entire width of the header. Adding `float:none;` to your rule `ul li ul li` kind of fixed this problem, but you might want to consider adding a max-width as well, so your layout stays consistent.